# DATA-TYPE is not a queryable attribute for BROWSE qBrowse1. (4052)

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I use below procedure and the table used doesn't have any data. When I run the program am getting DATA-TYPE is not a queryable attribute for BROWSE qBrowse1. (4052). Not sure where I am making mistakes.

```
define temp-table tt_scan_browse no-undo
field tb_ref as character.

empty temp-table tt_scan_browse

FOR EACH xxtable no-lock:
create tt_scan_browse.
assign
`tb_ref  = xxtable.ref
.
end.
OPEN QUERY query1 FOR EACH tt_scan_browse NO-LOCK.
ENABLE All WITH FRAME BrowseFrame.
APPLY 'ENTRY' to browse qBrowse1.
WAIT-FOR WINDOW-CLOSE OF CURRENT-WINDOW.
HIDE FRAME BrowseFrame.
```

Comment: There must be code somewhere that queries the DATA-TYPE attribute. Please extend the question to include that code.

Comment: To find out /where/ your error is originating from, add ``-debugalert`` as startup parameter or set ``session:debug-alert = true``, your error message will have an additional ``Help`` button that will provide the stack trace of your error.